# Draw a nonlinear equation

Tags: swift, macos

I have a nonlinear equation and I need to draw its 2D plot.

I have found third-party solutions such as CorePlot, but I would like to know if there is a way to draw it using standard Swift features?

Comment: As i can see, CoreGraphics is much difficult way. I'll use Charts. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is Core Graphics. It's not easy to do.

A good hint, how to do this might give you the [open source project Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts).

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to do. An example of how to draw a graph is given in this WWDC session, where it is explained how to stocks-app draws he graph with CoreGraphics. This was before Swift, but CoreGraphics is a C-api, so you can us it almost as-is in Swift.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/129/